# Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm trying to make my JavaFX Application visible, if I press CTRL + Alt + D (I'm using [jkeymaster](https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster)). But everytime I write Stage.show(); in my HotKeyListener I get `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0 (line 7)` (I also tested to show a file chooser in my hot key listener and outside of the listener and if I do the second thing I get no error). And also if I just put `System.out.println("Test")` in my hot key listener without the other things it just outputs it and I get no error

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static Stage s;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml")));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Test");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    s = stage;

}
```

}

Controller:

```
    public class Controller {

    public void initialize() {
        Provider provider = Provider.getCurrentProvider(true);
        openSaveDialog(Main.s); //No error
        HotKeyListener l = hotKey -> {
            Main.s.show();
            openSaveDialog(Main.s);
            //Returns an error
        };
        provider.register(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control alt D"), l);
    }

    public File openSaveDialog(Stage s) {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        chooser.setTitle("Select the output");
        return chooser.showSaveDialog(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try wrapping the contents of the `HotKeyListener` in a call to `Platform.runLater()` this should fix it. Since you're modifying the JavaFX Scene graph, this work must be done on the Application thread.

```java
HotKeyListener l = hotKey -> {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Main.s.show();
        openSaveDialog(Main.s);
    });
};
```

Although, instead of using the AWT HotKeyListener, you should really register a key listener through JavaFX's events. Then you wouldn't need to call `Platform.runLater()`

Comment: As a note, you can call Platform.isFxApplicationThread() to check whether your code is running on the JavaFX application thread, or some other thread.

Comment: I used jkeymaster because I wanted to Press a key combination without a window opened. I have not found anything else

Comment: So now I have the problem if I press the key combination again, nothing happens?

Comment: nvm found the problem